# Sequelize operation hanging when returning the result but working when no returning it

Tags: node.js, promise, sequelize.js

I've been working with Node for about 3 years, but what is happening to me right now is driving me crazy.

My project uses Sequelize for the last 6 months and it's all working perfectly.

If I try to update the *myModelObject* instance with the following code, it works as expected.(*I've change the real code in order to show the behavior in a more cleaner way*)

```
...
.then(parameters => {                                    
   myModelObject.update({parameters}, { where: { id: myObjectId }})
   .then(() => {
      console.log("Sequelize update resolved !")      
   })
})
.then( () => {
   console.log("Promise resolved !")
})
```

This will make my myModelObject updated in the DB and the console will display:

> Promise resolved !

1 second later...

> Sequelize update resolved !

**But**, the strange behavior happens when I add a **return** before the update of myModelObject:

```
...
.then(parameters => {                                    
   return myModelObject.update({parameters}, { where: { id: myObjectId }})
   .then(() => {
      console.log("Sequelize update resolved !")
   })
})
.then( () => {
   console.log("Promise resolved !")
})
```

This makes my code to hung.. the update is never done and a timeout happens. What I mean is that the Sequelize update is never resolved if I want to return it !
All my other Sequelize code is working perfectly !

Any hep will be very appreciate it :)

*Node: 12.16.0 || Sequelize: 5.21.6 || pg: 7.18.2*

Comment: What do you want to return? A promise object or just a string "Sequelize update resolved !"

Comment: I just want to return the Promise of the Update so I can make an action once it is resolved, but if I add the return before the 'update', it hangs and doesn't ever resolve

Comment: suprised to see that your code is not working with `return` !!

Comment: Exactly.. is driving me crazy

Comment: What you are describing here is not possible, given the code you show. There must be something else going on that you omitted in your example.

Comment: Yes, but that is happening.... it took me to the point where I really doubted if I understood the use of promises, because if the 'Update' hangs, then it should hang always independently if is returning the promise or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, I found the problem !.

Before this method is called, in another part of the code, a Sequelize Transaction was being used to update this same object and the transaction was not yet committed.

Apparently this causes my update to hang.

To solve it, I also passed this transaction to my Update call. Another way to fix it would be to end the transaction before calling my update.

Comment: Wow I had the exact same problem. This probably saved me hours of debugging.

Answer (score -1):

@oriuken, maybe you should try something like this below.

```
.then(parameters => {   
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      await myModelObject.update({parameters}, { where: { id: myObjectId }});
      console.log("Sequelize update resolved !")
      return resolve('Promise resolved')
    }catch(e) {
      return reject(e.message);
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: I tried something similar but no luck. I also tried this code of yours too but no luck neither.. the code hungs when making the 'update'

Comment: Bad use of promises. Creating extra needless promises, plus `return resolve` and `return reject` do nothing, see Promise spec.

Comment: Extra needless promise? please read the actual question again and the comment section. The reason i have used return, it should ideally be your last statement within your function.  Also, do nothing? you will see the "Promise resolved" if you log it. with or without return keyword because resolve and reject are callback functions.